# Is there a way to "reset" mobile Webkit's pseudo-hover behaviour after the initial hover-triggering click?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mobile-safari, touchscreen

I'm working on a website where I'm using Javascript (via JQuery) to add pop-up boxes containing extra information for items in a list. I'm using JQuery's `mouseeneter` and `mouseleave` events to make the popups appear and disappear which of course all works fine in desktop browsers.

In Mobile Safari the popup appears when I click an item (which is what I expect and what I want to happen) and I have added an `ontouchstart` which triggers the `mouseleave` JQuery event thus hiding any visible pop-up when the user does anything else. This works fine too except that when a user taps an item the pop-up of which they've just looked at and cancelled (either by scrolling or by doing anything else that triggers the `ontouchstart` event), rather than it showing the pop-up again it activates the link attached to that item.

If a user were to tap another item instead of tapping the same item again then that new item's pop-up would show and then if they were to tap the first item again then that item's pop-up would show. Again, this is both expected and what I want to happen.

It would seem that once an item with a hover event has been tapped and Mobile Safari as been forced to make that event happen, that item is then flagged as having had its hover event triggered and so the next tap doesn't have to pretend to be a hover, it can be a normal click. Tapping another item with a hover event seems to "reset" the flag set for the previous item.

I'd like to be able to 'reset' this flag for myself so that, rather than how things work currently where clicking an item shows the pop-up and the next click on that item, even if the pop-up has been closed, will activate the link, instead when I close the pop-up with my `ontouchstart`, and so to my mind the item is no longer being "hovered over", a second click on that same item should show the pop-up again and then only by clicking on the item whilst the pop-up is visible should the link activate.

The secret would seem to be in getting Mobile Safari to exit its "pseudo-hover" mode when I use `ontouchstart` to trigger `mouseleave` but I have been unable to find anything useful anywhere on exactly what's going on when Mobile Safari pretends to hover over anything and whether any of this is accessible via Javascript events.

I know I could write a version of my pop-up code to work specifically for Mobile Safari but it seems much more efficient to me to get the browser to do most of the hard work of mimicking hover events. If only I could get this final little niggle sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the hover state is tied into which element has focus rather than as a flag. One tap gives focus, second tap activates the link.

Try closing the pop-up by giving another element focus, and see if that works out any better.

```
$('body').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr but try this:

```
# :hover fix
# e.g.: body:not(.stoppedhovering) .styled:hover
hoverFix = ->
  window.clearTimeout hoverFix.delay if hoverFix.delay?
  $('body').removeClass 'stoppedhovering'
  delayed = -> $('body').addClass 'stoppedhovering'
  hoverFix.delay = _.delay delayed, 600
$('*').live 'touchstart', hoverFix
```

Comment: btw this is coffeescript + underscore, but im sure u can deduce the js :)